Romance movie from late nineties about two young people who do smart talk
I've been looking for this movie for ages, but it's really hard to remember specific things like actors or plot details, as I have seen it some 15+ years ago.
This is one of those movies about love, about two, kind-of-young people in their late 18s or early 20s.
They meet and talk a lot, discussing lots of things, mostly about relationships and stuff like that.
I remember this one very specific moment where they lay on the grass and both look at the sky and say witty, smart things (sorry can't really phrase it better).
I think this is a somewhat low(er) budget romance movie (nothing with Keanu or another hugely known actor), but still, modern and potentially good enough to make it to the TV screens of where I am from (which is Portugal BTW).
I'm thinking American, but possibly a cross-country romance with an American and a European.

Before Sunrise

@madmada wow that is a great find. you certainly hit all the markers. I'm not entirely sure this is the one I'm thinking, but I will take a look

I was thinking of "Before sunrise" too from that description, but it really doesn't match our usual requirements for identification questions.

I think one of the problems with SO/SE is that some people are too eager to downvote and close and they give zero opportunity for users like madmada to speak up and potentially be a huge help. sometimes questions arent perfect but if people manage not to kill the question in the first 6 hours, the asker may just get what he is looking for, and isn't that what this is all about in the end of the day

@madmada had a chance to see the movie. was doubtful at first but I think this is it. feel free to reply as an answer so I can accept it, and again, thanks for your help

Glad you found it and btw it's a well known movie and has two sequels, Before Sunset (one of my all times favorites) and Before Midnight. All of them are highly rated. I think one of them was in IMDB top 250 movie list a while ago.

Before Sunrise

A young man and woman meet on a train in Europe, and wind up spending one evening together in Vienna. Unfortunately, both know that this will probably be their only night together. 




